# Looping all pairwise comparisons from a list in R

Tags: r, function, loops, lapply

In my R code below, suppose I want to compare all unique 2 `m` objects using a similar R routine. For example, to compare `m1` and `m2`, my routine is:

`pchisq(2 * (logLik(m2) - logLik(m1)), df = abs(m1$df.residual - m2$df.residual), lower = F)`

**Question:**

I was wondering how I could make a function to make all unique pairwise comparisons for all `m` objects using my routine?

Here is what I've tried without success:

```
## Suppose we have 4 `m` objects: `m1...m4` (6 unique pairwise comparisons possible)

m1 <- lm(hp ~ vs, mtcars)
m2 <- lm(hp ~ vs*wt, mtcars)
m3 <- lm(hp ~., mtcars)
m4 <- lm(hp ~ vs * gear * wt, mtcars)


 compare <- function(...){

   m <- list(...)
   L <- length(m) - 1

   lapply(1:L, function(i) pchisq(2 * (logLik(m[[i+1]]) - logLik(m[[i]])), df = abs(m[[i]]$df.residual - m[[i+1]]$df.residual), lower.tail = FALSE) )

  }
# Example of use:
compare(m1, m2, m3, m4)
```

Comment: Not what you asked for but possibly what you really need is: `anova(m1, m2, m4, m3, test = "Chisq")`

Comment: The class of the models shown in the question is `lm` and `anova` supports that and there are many other methods as well.  If you are using something not shown suggest you mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combn` to get all combinations you want to compare:

```
compare <- function(...){

  m <- list(...)
  n_mod <- length(m)
  names(m) <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
  combs <- t(combn(x = names(m), m = 2))

  comp_value <- apply(X = combs, MARGIN = 1, function(ind) pchisq(2 * (logLik(m[[ind[2]]]) - logLik(m[[ind[1]]])), df = abs(m[[ind[1]]]$df.residual - m[[ind[2]]]$df.residual), lower.tail = FALSE))
  df_out <- data.frame(combs, comp_value)
  names(df_out) <- c("mod_1", "mod_2", "comp_value")

  return(df_out)
}
```

So, to make it easier to read the result, you can return a `data.frame` with all the comparisons.

Then

```
compare(m1, m2, m3, m4)
  mod_1 mod_2   comp_value
1    m1    m2 2.391012e-02
2    m1    m3 7.253068e-08
3    m1    m4 1.248692e-06
4    m2    m3 2.735901e-07
5    m2    m4 4.256098e-06
6    m3    m4 1.000000e+00
```

Comment: Douglas, thank you once again. But I have realized that your function throws an error when I compare 2 fitted models from the `glmmTMB` package, like so:  `m1 <- glmmTMB(count~ mined + (1|site),
               zi=~mined,
               family=poisson, data=Salamanders)` and `m2 <- glmmTMB(count~spp + mined + (1|site),
               zi=~spp + mined,
               family=nbinom2, Salamanders)`. And now when I do `compare(m1, m2)`, I get the following error: `Error in -object$fit$objective : invalid argument to unary operator`. The problem is with your third line (containing `sapply`)?

Comment: The problem is that the `glmmTMB` class does not have this entry: `m1$df.residuals`.

Comment: Douglas, thank you.  hummm, could you possibly think of a fix?

Comment: In this class you can get the degrees of freedom using `glmmTMB:::df.residual.glmmTMB(mod)`. So you need to use this code instead of `mod$df.residuals` in the function. In addition, you can add a step in the function: `if(class(mod) == "glmmTMB") df <- glmmTMB:::df.residual.glmmTMB(mod)` otherwise use the current function.